# Hyperbolic analog of atan2(y,x)?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

Background:

Many math libraries provide `hypot(y,x)` and `atan2(y,x)` as numerically robust routines for converting Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, with `hypot` providing the magnitude and `atan2` providing the angle.  The two parameter version of the inverse tangent, having complete knowledge of the quadrant from which the point originated, can recover any angle between -pi and pi, whereas `atan(y/x)` loses that information and can only represent half of that range.

Question:

Is there any analog to `atan2` for computing the hyperbolic angle from Cartesian coordinates, or do hyperbolas sidestep the issues that needed to be addressed for circles?  More generally, what is the canonical polar decomposition of a split-complex number - is information about the quadrant where the point originated maintained, or is the conversion to polar form intrinsically lossy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we introduce real coordinates $\rho,\,phi$ with $x=\rho\cosh\phi,\,y=\rho\sinh\phi$ so that $y=x\tanh\phi$, the sign of $x$ determines that of $\rho$, so the situation isn't analogous to ordinary polar coordinates needing $\operatorname{atan2}$. There's a further difference: you can only describe points with $|x|>|y|$.

Comment: Can points with |x| < |y| be represented if either the magnitude or angle are allowed to take on imaginary (or complex) values?

Comment: @Jason You'd need imaginary values for $\rho,\,\cosh\phi,\,\sinh\phi$. I'll leave finding the relevant $\phi$ as an exercise.